# Swift code compiles fine on iOS, gives warning on OSX: Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type 'SKPaymentTransactionState`

Tags: ios, macos, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have a swift file that I'm using in a couple applications (one being OSX, one being iOS). The code compiles and works fine on iOS, but fails to compile on OSX. Here's the iOS friendly code:

```
if let transactionsArray = transactions as? [SKPaymentTransaction]{
        for transaction in transactionsArray{
            switch transaction.transactionState{
            case .Failed,.Purchased,.Restored:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

I can change it to:

```
if let transactionsArray = transactions as? [SKPaymentTransaction]{
        for transaction in transactionsArray{
            switch transaction.transactionState{
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed, SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

and it'll fix it for OSX— but then iOS throws a fit. I can't seem to come up with anything that'll keep them both happy.

Looking at the documentation, I see that on OSX, SKPaymentTransactionState is define as:

```
typealias SKPaymentTransactionState = Int
```

where as on iOS the type is define as:

```
enum SKPaymentTransactionState : Int {
    case Purchasing
    case Purchased
    case Failed
    case Restored
    case Deferred
}
```

I really don't want to do a `#if os(iOS)… #else …`, so what is the proper way to deal with this discrepancy?

Comment: Since the type is defined in both iOS and OS X, and it's only a typealias in the latter, I see no other approach than to use a conditional flag (`#if os(iOS)`) and have two separate switch statements that call the same functions from within the case blocks. I think this would probably be addressed in a later update so I wouldn't mess too much with types to make them match.